# Atom text editor; Shortcuts for moving to bottom of file, moving to end of line

Tags: text-editor, atom

How do I move to the bottom of a file, top of a file, end of a line and beginning of a line in the Atom text editor (atom.io)?

I can not find any shortcuts for that text editor. Only shortcuts for OSX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll post a few tips here:

1. Use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> to select all and then press <kbd>↑</kbd> to go to the top or <kbd>↓</kbd> to go to the bottom of the file. For the beginning / end of a line try <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>→</kbd> or if it doesn't work try the same with <kbd>shift</kbd> or <kbd>alt</kbd>.
2. You can use the `vim plugin` for atom and this will make all of these (and much more) possible. So with the `vim plugin` you can use in `command mode`: `gg` to go to the top of a file, `G` to go to the end, `$` to go to the end of a line, `0` to go to the beginning of a line, `^` to go to the first non-empty character on a line. Read more about it [here](http://hea-www.harvard.edu/~fine/Tech/vi.html).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Ctrl-a and then up_arrow works, but ctrl/alt/shift-left_arrow does not work. But never mind, I think I will install the vim plugin, thanks for that!

Answer (score 3):

This applies to almost any text editor:

- <kbd>Ctrl + Home</kbd> go to beginning of the file.
- <kbd>Ctrl + End</kbd> go to end of the file.
- <kbd>Home</kbd> go to beginning of the line.
- <kbd>End</kbd> go to end of the line.

Also, <kbd>Ctrl + Left / Right arrows</kbd> jump between words.

For Macbook keyboards [use <kbd>Fn + arrows</kbd>](https://superuser.com/a/132722/500826).

Comment: Unfortunately the Home and End keys don't exist on a macbook pro keyboard.

Comment: @Simon Tell us if [this](https://www.apple.com/uk/shop/question/answers/readonly/how-can-i-make-the-home-and-end-keys-on-the-apple-extended-keyboard-work-as-line-commands-rather-than-page-commands/Q7HY7K2UFDTUK7J7C?tagName=mac) or [this](https://www.cnet.com/how-to/two-mac-keyboard-shortcuts-for-missing-home-and-end-keys/) help you.

Comment: Fn + arrow keys do the trick! Thanks! Now just need to re-wire my brain :P